# How to make a menu for the mobile site opens in full screen?

Tags: css, google-chrome, position

Why in chrome, safari and some other mobile browsers fixed horizontal menu ( with position: fixed; top: 0 ; left: 0 ; ) is not in the top of a mobile screen?

With the active use of the site , primarily scrolling menu moves a few pixels from the top , sometimes little more than a few .

With what it can be connected and how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your CSS

```
body{
margin:0px;
}
```

I hope it will fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but your solution doesn't solve my problem)  Try to explain more detailed... When i open my site on mobile devices (first of all ios chrome), everything is alright, but if i scroll top and refresh my page by dragging down my page (chrome option - alternative method of button refreshing) - appears a distance between the top of screen and the top of my menu... This distance is always different. Thank you